# nla editor - meta strips on multiple object base?

Tags: animation, nla-editor

so far, I thought that NLA meta strips were good for sorting a whole scene's animation (and beyond). But I only found functionality on a per-oobject base.

What I mean:
in my animation setup, several objects' animations are so closely linked together that it does not make any sense to edit them one by one. As the animation became more complex, I needed a way to efficiently tweak several objects' animations / timing. An example:

An armature is controlled by several IK target objects, which are part of a path animation. while the path is also animated. Over time, it becomes near-impossible to edit each object one by one in a timely manner.

I need a way to group these object's animations. So far, I thought that this can be done by meta strips. But it seems to be impossible. (if so: why? It's so basic...)

Is there a way (even if it's an addon) to do this efficiently (emphasis is on efficiency, as modelers are always on a time pressure...)

Answer (score 1):

I think this add-on may help you to achieve what your are trying to do. Please see the link for a video download and an explanation by "coyhot" the author.

[Animation Joiner](http://www.coyhot.com/addon-blender-animation-joiner/)

**Description of the content (from the link above):**

> Join them all !
>
> So, I'm proud to present my Animation Joiner. I designed it with
>   dynamic simulation in mind, but I found it could be usefull for
>   character animation, too. My goal was to merge animated objects into
>   only one mesh, animated by a MeshCache modifier and a PC2 file.
>
> Why a PC2 file ?
>
> PC2 is a binary cache file format, wildly use in production. It can be
>   nativaly streamed in 3DS Max and Blender, but can also be used in
>   Maya, Lightwave, Houdini, and many others. Because Blender doesn't
>   have Alembic support yet, PC2 is for me the best to way to interchange
>   animated object between 3D packages.
>
> But when I wrote this addon, I wasn't thinking of interchange format.
>   I was thinking of dynamic simulation, and more precisly Rigid Bodies.
>   I work a lot with rigid bodies in Blender. And the most difficult part
>   of the job is to manage cache files, specialy when you have thousands
>   of debris. I dreamed about a technic where you can manage multiple
>   debris as easy as only one mesh. And that's the goal of my addon.
>
> Reducing the complexity of the scene
>
> Select your debris, set the path to the PC2 file and click on Join
>   Animated Objects. After few seconds, on the next layer, you will find
>   only one animated mesh using a MeshCache modifier, streaming a PC2
>   file. Now, you can duplicate (linked) the mesh and multiply the number
>   of debris without rising the usage of the memory. And you can even
>   offset the animation ! If you generate two PC2 files for the same
>   debris, you can also crossfade from one Meshcache to another by using
>   the Influence parameter.
>
> Because you now have only one object, you can add any modifier on it,
>   like a Bevel for instance. But you can also emit particles from all
>   the debris really easily. You can even duplicate (linked) this object
>   and add a Collision modifier on it. By this way, particles will be
>   emitted by the debris, but they also bounce on them ! Try to do that
>   when you have hundred of debris ... not so easy.
>
> Same thing for the smoke : you can try to emit smoke from the debris,
>   with a duplicated object set as a collider. With only two objects, you
>   can see the smoke flowing through every holes in a falling wall !
>
> Reshaping and retiming dynamic simulation
>
> Because you have only one object, you can deform it during the
>   animation by using a lattice of even shape keys. In the demonstration
>   video bellow, you can see that I tweak the position of only one debris
>   because it intersect with another one. You can also emit particles and
>   use an Explode modifier, followed by a Solidify to generate more
>   smaller debris.
>
> MeshCache can be animated using different options. One of my favorite
>   is the one named "Custom". Because, you can timeremap you simulation
>   by only creating keyframes, slow it down (the position of each point
>   will be interpolated !) if you want to create a slowmotion shot of a
>   falling building, without the need to simulate it at an higher
>   framerate !
>
> Maybe I'm wrong, but I think it's easier for Blender to manage fewer
>   objects with an high polygons number than a lot of objects with fewer
>   polygons. I think it's because of the dependancy graph. So, if you
>   take a look at the first image of this post, 4 millions polygons are
>   used to generate debris of all the buildings. But I can run the
>   animation at 3 FPS and it only take 500 Mb in RAM, because of the
>   instances used in the scene. And last but not the least, Cycles start
>   almost immediatly when I launch an interactive rendering !